# Impossible to install qgis 2.18 on ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: qgis

After many tries and consulting numerous advices, I failed to install QGIS 2.18 on ubuntu 16.10 (xenial). The system returned to install QGIS 2.14. I read somewhere in a forum that it could be impossible, because of dependencies issues.
I want to know if somebody has a receipt to resolve that or if we have to wait for QGIS 3.0 announced for (may-be) next spring.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly fuller answer. Add the sources to your /etc/apt/sources.list file by entering the following text on the command line in a terminal window:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

*(I know there are cleaner ways to do that, but **gksu** is not working on my system for some reason.)* 
This pops open a text window in gedit with all the software package repository addresses in it. Do not change anything else in this file; at the very bottom just add:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian yakkety main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian yakkety main
```

Now do the update command (below), but know that it will fail the first time:

```
sudo apt update
```

Around the 5th line, my terminal returned an ERR and said the public key for this archive was unavailable. However, it also gave the number of that 'unavailable' public key in the error message: 073D307A618E5811. Thus, we can manually enter the pub_key and get this all to work:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45
```

Now you can do:

```
sudo apt update
```

...again, and the repository should update successfully. At this point you could just install the latest versions of qgis and python via the following:

```
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

...or you could update **all** the files that become upgradable with this update of the package repository.

Comment: I am getting a " GPG error: http://qgis.org/debian yakkety InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY CAEB3DC3BDF7FB45"

Comment: I updated the answer with GPG instructions based on the QGIS Installer documentation: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html

Comment: However, now I get a lot of dependency errors, and still cannot install QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

add to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://qgis.org/debian yakkety main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian yakkety main
```

then type

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```